# Recording Facebook Messenger Video call on Android

Tags: applications, whatsapp-messenger, facebook, video-recording, facebook-messenger

**Hi All,**

I am trying to record a Facebook messenger video call on Android 9.0.

i used many application but the issue is when i open the app then start the v-call the other side can't hear me -but i can-

and if i open the app during any normal v-call and go back to the recording it would be without sound !! even though the call was fine.

any one can help ? or explain what happening so we can solve this ?

> note: if i use Whatsapp video call is that going to make any
>   difference ?

**Thank you**